# Linkedin Connection API didn't return new connections

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am using linked connection API in my application and trying to get newly added connection of authenticate user. But it always return all connections of authenticate user.

Here is my reference link:

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api#

and API call is:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id)?oauth2_access_token=Auth_token&format=json&modified=new&modified-since=1385014447

It should return modified and new connection while its return all connections. Is there problem with my API Calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way

```
$miliseconds= $sconds*100;
```

and send that miliseconds in query string

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id)?oauth2_access_token=Auth_token&format=json&modified=new&modified-since=$miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

The API requires *milliseconds* since epoch, not seconds. You're asking for all connections since 1/17/1970 12:43:34 AM. :)

Comment: It's return empty connection array with milliseconds.